# Count and take average of not null columns in a single row

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2008

I want to count and take average of not null columns in each row
for example, i have a table like this

```
Name | a  | b  | c  | d  | e   | f |
     |    |    |    |    |     |   |
umar | 2  |null| 3  | 5  | null| 4 |
ali  |null|null| 3  |null| 1   | 4 |
ali  |null|null| 3  |null| null| 4 |
```

the result should be

```
    Name | a  | b  | c  | d  | e   | f | average
         |    |    |    |    |     |   |
    umar | 2  |null| 3  | 5  | null| 4 |  3.5
    ali  |null|null| 3  |null| 1   | 4 |  2.66
    ali  |null|null| 3  |null| null| 4 | 3.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = from x in table
            select new 
            {
                CountNotNull = (x.a ?? 0) + (x.b ?? 0) + (x.c ?? 0) + (x.d ?? 0) + (x.e ?? 0) + (x.f ?? 0) 
            };
```

If you don't want to count it but calculate the average(you've changed the question):

```
var query = 
     from x in table
     let NotNullColCount = (x.a == null ? 0 : 1) + (x.b == null ? 0 : 1) + (x.c == null ? 0 : 1) + (x.d == null ? 0 : 1) + (x.e == null ? 0 : 1) + (x.f == null ? 0 : 1)
     let NotNullColSum = (x.a ?? 0) + (x.b ?? 0) + (x.c ?? 0) + (x.d ?? 0) + (x.e ?? 0) + (x.f ?? 0)
     select new 
     {
        AverageNotNull = NotNullColCount == 0 
                         ? 0.0 
                         : 1.0 * NotNullColSum / NotNullColCount 
     };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `case` expression for this:

```
select ((case when a is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when b is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when c is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when d is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when e is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when f is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as NumNotNull
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.name,
       (CASE WHEN t.a is not null then 1 else 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.b is not null then 1 else 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.c is not null then 1 else 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.d is not null then 1 else 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.e is not null then 1 else 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.f is not null then 1 else 0 END) as not_null_count
FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: thanks. if i want to take average of every row (sum not null columns divided by the not null count)?? @sagi

Comment: Mmm yea , wrap it with another query and do `SUM(not_null_count)/COUNT(*)` @MuhammadTauseen

Comment: I have updated my question. please check how i want result. @sagi

Comment: @MuhammadTauseen: i've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38305372/284240) according to your changed question

Comment: `IFNULL` function does not exists in `SQL SERVER`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dynamic query ,if your number of columns are large

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT Tablename.Columnname , ' + 
    STUFF((SELECT '+ CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + 
        ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Tablename' FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '') 
    + ' FROM Tablename';
EXEC(@SQL);

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL may help you out:

```
SELECT  Name
      , a
      , b
      , c
      , d
      , e
      , f
      , CONVERT(FLOAT, ( tab.a1 + tab.b1 + tab.c1 + tab.d1 + tab.e1 + tab.f1 )) / CONVERT(FLOAT, ( tab.a2 + tab.b2
                                                                                                   + tab.c2 + tab.d2
                                                                                                   + tab.e2 + tab.f2 )) AS [average]
FROM    ( SELECT    Name
                  , a
                  , b
                  , c
                  , d
                  , e
                  , f
                  , CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE a
                    END AS a1
                  , CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE b
                    END AS b1
                  , CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE c
                    END AS c1
                  , CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE d
                    END AS d1
                  , CASE WHEN e IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE e
                    END AS e1
                  , CASE WHEN f IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE f
                    END AS f1
                  , CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE 1
                    END AS a2
                  , CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE 1
                    END AS b2
                  , CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE 1
                    END AS c2
                  , CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE 1
                    END AS d2
                  , CASE WHEN e IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE 1
                    END AS e2
                  , CASE WHEN f IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE 1
                    END AS f2
          FROM      YourTable
        ) tab
```